# Custom commands/drawings as nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make cubes that are next to one another in a grid like pattern. I figured the best way to do this would be to use nodes and then just place my drawings there. I found from [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/need-help-creating-a-3d-cube-from-a-2d-set-of-nodes-in-tikz) how to write a custom command to make arbitrary cubes (in a formatting I want). What I would like to end up with is something like

```latex
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \node[\tikzcube{3}{1}] (c0) {};
   \node[\tikzcube{4}{1}, right=10cm] (c1) {};
   \node[\tikzcube{2}{1}, below=10cm] (c2) {};
   ... so on ...
```

Where `\tikzcube` is a custom command that performs drawings (as seen in the linked post).

Comment: Welcome! This is precisely what so-called pic's are for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just copied the definition of the cube from [your link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29877/need-help-creating-a-3d-cube-from-a-2d-set-of-nodes-in-tikz) and made them `pic's. The syntax is very similar to what you are suggesting.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\newcommand{\tikzcuboid}[3]{% width, height, depth, scale
\foreach \x in {0,...,#1}
{   \draw (\x ,0  ,#3 ) -- (\x ,#2 ,#3 );
    \draw (\x ,#2 ,#3 ) -- (\x ,#2 ,0  );
}
\foreach \x in {0,...,#2}
{   \draw (#1 ,\x ,#3 ) -- (#1 ,\x ,0  );
    \draw (0  ,\x ,#3 ) -- (#1 ,\x ,#3 );
}
\foreach \x in {0,...,#3}
{   \draw (#1 ,0  ,\x ) -- (#1 ,#2 ,\x );
    \draw (0  ,#2 ,\x ) -- (#1 ,#2 ,\x );
}
}

\newcommand{\tikzcube}[1]{% length, scale
\tikzcuboid{#1}{#1}{#1}
}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[pics/cube/.style={code={\tikzcube{#1}}}]
  \pic (c0) {cube=3} ;
  \pic[right=10cm] (c1) {cube=4};
  \pic[below=10cm] (c2) {cube=2};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome! This is exactly what I was looking for. (btw, I misread the intention of your above comment and didn't realize you mean the `\pic` command, which I didn't know about)

Comment: If I wanted to in turn use `cuboid` then how do I modify it. I'm trying `\begin{tikzpicture}[pic/cuboid/.style={code={\tikzcuboid{#1}{#2}{#3}}}]` and getting an illegal parameter number error

Comment: @StevenWalton It needs to be `\begin{tikzpicture}[pic/cuboid/.style n args={3}{code={\tikzcuboid{#1}{#2}{#3}}}]` but I personally do not like to use pics with so many *mandatory* arguments. Rather, I prefer to store them in pgf keys like e.g.  in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/489719.